# Passing a MongoDB collection to an array in NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, promise

I'm having an issue with getting data out of a MongoDB collection and return it into an array in my code in NodeJS.

The code so far returns a promise, that I don't fully know how to handle.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
async function loadData() {

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        console.log('Attempting to connect to DB')
        client.connect(async err => {
            const collection = client.db("db").collection("collection");
            await collection.find({}).toArray().then((data) => {

            //Getting stumped as the data gets returned as a promise and does not get added to an array

            }
            );

        client.close();
        console.log('Closed DB connection');

        });
    } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Don't execute the Promise inside the loadData function 


 function loadData() {

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        console.log('Attempting to connect to DB')
        client.connect(async err => {
            const collection = client.db("db").collection("collection");
            return collection.find({})
            );

        client.close();
        console.log('Closed DB connection');

        });
    } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    }
```

And mak a call to get your Data

```
try {
  const your_Array = await loadData().toArray();
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

And for the MongoDB connection, I think you're doing it wrong , Follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dshster/4a80e13ab306c55fa15f62cd8c7c18cb)

Comment: Thank you! :) However, I have to note that I'm not using mongoose. Instead, I'm using the official MongoDB connector

Comment: Using an ORM will provide for you more functionality than the official connector !

Answer (score 1):

You are using promises wrong as well as `async` `await`. The purpose of async/await is to avoid using the `.then` function. Pick one, use either or.

using callback method:

```
collection.find({}).toArray().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}, err => {
  // this gets called if there is an error only
  console.log(err);
});
```

or with async/await:

```
try {
  const data = await collection.find({}).toArray();
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

note that if you choose to use async/await, the containing function must be marked `async`, which you're already doing. This is not required if you use the above callback method.